# Forms Authentication - Login prompt opening office documents

Tags: wss-3.0, forms-authentication, office-integration

I have a pretty common problem with WSS 3.0

When a user logs on to the site using IE 7/8 and opens a word document from a document library he gets prompted for a login / password. At this point, even when cancel is pressed or when the login window is closed the document still opens.

This problem is document online (and here : [Forms Authentication, persistent cookie needed by IE, but not Firefox or Chrome](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27216/forms-authentication-persistent-cookie-needed-by-ie-but-not-firefox-or-chrome))

The solution is to either :

- Add the site to the trusted zone (I can't do that, I have a public-facing website so my users come from everywhere)
- Disable client integration

I disabled client integration (through Central Administration > Authentication Providers) and I still get the problem.

What else do I need to do to disable client integration? Am I missing something? Is there something else I can do to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a HttpModule helping out with this in my blog post [Remove Login box when anonymous users download office document from SharePoint Site](http://www.theblackknightsings.com/RemoveLoginBoxWhenAnonymousUsersDownloadOfficeDocumentFromSharePointSite.aspx)

Depending on your version of office you may have to extend the list of rejected User Agents in the code.

Comment: Sorry it took a while to get back to you. This works perfectly. Had not seen this fix when I looked the problem up. Can't say I really understand what's going on though... I presume that if I had the problem with office 2010 I would block MSFrontPage/14.0, is that what you meant? In any case, thank you very much for your help, much appreciated!