# with FBA, How to get rid of Login popup while opening document in library

Tags: document-library, forms-authentication, login, custom-login-page

I've enabled fba with custom login page.
I've document library.While trying to open document, it asks for credentials everytime. Due to FBA with custom login page, it does not close the login popup automatically.

How can I get this resolved?

Comment: Have you test it with Firefox/Chrome ? Does it only appear with IE ? This is a [Similar post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/3b152c99-c3da-4ef5-a0e2-494bda6d9289/fba-enabled-how-to-get-rid-of-the-login-popup-when-open-a-document-without-check-sign-me-in?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious) that should help you. You can have a look at links present in the post. Hope this help. EDIT : Please also check this [blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/steve_chen/archive/2010/06/25/multiple-logon-while-open-office-document-from-sharepoint.aspx).

Comment: I think its a doublon cause of [this](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/46956/forms-authentication-login-prompt-opening-office-documents)